# How to redirect to login page from protected webpages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, security, authentication

I want to authenticate a user before they access a few .html pages that should only be seen when logged in.

Right now I have been making a GET request to my backend to complete this, but the process takes a little bit of time and the webpage does end up loading and flashes its content for about a half second before the server realizes its a non-authenticated user and starts redirecting. 
Is there a more secure/better way to handle this?

(by the way i am using auth0 for authentication)

Comment: are you using some library like react for front end?

Comment: just plain css, html, and javascript. Bootstrap for layout

Comment: check this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vanilla-router, it can take a function that applied when redirect. I was thinking may be you can apply a loader untill the response comes from the server